# Sum of multiple values of one variable

Tags: sql, count, sum, dynamic-sql

I want to sum the variable that is holding the value in a loop,

Here's my table:

```
name | pkey | cinema1~cinema10 | total_QTy | total_sales
aaa  |  1   |  100.00 ~ 200.00 |     2     |  300.00
bbb  |  2   |  150.00 ~ 145.00 |     3     |  295.00
```

total_Qty is the sum of the tickets bought in cinema1~cinema10 for name aaa
and I don't know how to do this. I am only getting the last value of counted ticket which is in name bbb cinema10.

Help me please. I'm stuck here.

Here is my code for getting the amount and qty

```
WHILE ISNULL(@cinema_key, 0) <> 0
BEGIN

    SET @amount = 0


SELECT @amount =(SUM(t1.price)), @qty = (count(t1.cnt))
FROM(
    SELECT 
           (ISNULL(SUM(mctrs.price),0) - (ISNULL(SUM(mctrs.lgu_tax_amount),0) + ISNULL(SUM(mctrs.ordinance_1),0) + ISNULL(SUM(mctrs.ordinance_2),0)+ ISNULL(SUM(mctrs.ordinance_3),0) + ISNULL(SUM(mctrs.ordinance_4),0) ))   AS 'price', 
           count(mctrs.[key]) as 'cnt', mctrs.[key] as ckey
    FROM
    movie_calendar mc
    INNER JOIN
    movie_database md
    ON
    mc.movie_key = md.[key] AND mc.screening_start_date = @tdate
    INNER JOIN
    cinemas c
    ON
    mc.cinema_key = c.[key] AND c.[key] = @cinema_key
    INNER JOIN
    movie_calendar_times mct
    ON
    mct.movie_calendar_key = mc.[key]
    LEFT OUTER JOIN
    movie_calendar_time_reserved_seats mctrs
    ON
    mctrs.movie_calendar_time_key = mct.[key]
    INNER JOIN
    patrons p
    ON
    mctrs.patron_key = p.[key]
    WHERE mctrs.status = 1 AND mctrs.[committed]=1
    GROUP BY p.patron_tag,mctrs.price,P.APPLY_LGU_TAX ,P.LGU_TAX_AMOUNT, mctrs.[key]

)t1

    SET @buffer = 'UPDATE #temptable SET cinema'+CAST(@count AS VARCHAR)+' = '+CAST(ISNULL(sum(@amount),0) AS VARCHAR)+' WHERE [date] = '''+CAST (@tdate AS VARCHAR)+''''

    PRINT (@buffer)
    EXEC(@buffer)
    insert into #tqty(qty) values(@qty)

    DELETE FROM #cinema_list WHERE cinema_key = @cinema_key

    SET @cinema_key = NULL
    SET @cinema_code = NULL

    SELECT TOP 1 @cinema_key = cinema_key, @cinema_code = cinema_code FROM #cinema_list ORDER BY display_order

    SET @count = @count + 1

END /*WHILE CINEMA KEY*/
```

and here's my code in updating the total_Qty and total_sales:

```
WHILE @count < @cinema_count
BEGIN
    SET @count = @count+1.
    SET @select = @select+'cinema'+CAST(@count AS VARCHAR)+'+' 
END
SET @select = SUBSTRING(@select, 1, LEN(@select) - 1)
SET @buffer = 'UPDATE #temptable SET total_quantity = ' +cast(@qty as varchar) + ', ' + 'total_sales = '+@select 
PRINT @buffer
EXEC( @buffer)
```

Help please :3 Thanks :)

Comment: what is the meaning of "cinema1~cinema10"?

Comment: ooops sorry, cinema1~cinema10 is a dynamic column, the count of cinemas depends on DB.

Comment: Hey @Dakoy:  Sorry to point this out but using "dynamic" columns (cinema1, cinema2, ...) is almost always the wrong thing to do in a SQL database design.  Any chance the structure can be changed to "Cinema_id" and "Price" with rows containing ("1",100)("10",200)?  It would make this problem quite trivial: SELECT cinema_id, sum(price) from tablex group by cinema_id.  Even if you can't change the internal structure, it might make sense to prepare a proper structure before reporting and analysis...Even if temporary.

Answer (score 0):

I agree with @Dave Collins that this isn't database design at its greatest however if you want the simple answer, you need to add the existing value to the running total in your update.

Change this:

```
SET @buffer = 'UPDATE #temptable SET cinema'+CAST(@count AS VARCHAR)+' = '+CAST(ISNULL(sum(@amount),0) AS VARCHAR)+' WHERE [date] = '''+CAST (@tdate AS VARCHAR)+''''
```

To this:

```
SET @buffer = 'UPDATE #temptable SET cinema'+CAST(@count AS VARCHAR)+' = ISNULL(cinema,0) + '+CAST(ISNULL(sum(@amount),0) AS VARCHAR)+' WHERE [date] = '''+CAST (@tdate AS VARCHAR)+''''
```